# How to put a component in other component in runtime for angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to create a component in Angular2 which will show a table with some data(lets assume sales data of different product P1 and P2). Along with the table I want to allow user to choose option between different type of graphs and based on the graph selection I want to show the graph of shown data in a container below the data table.

I have created a component(lets call it Main) which have  as one component, A radio group showing graph type. Now for 10 different graph type, and I have created 10 different graph component for these 10 types.

Approach:
I can put all ten component in Main component and based on user selection I show the respective graph component. But this approach would be too costly since Main component shadow dom will have all the graph component. It also present problem If I allow user to select from a range of time and update the shown graph using binding as it will result in updating other graph which are not being shown.

Is there any approach where I can put a generic container in Main component and inject a list of graph component in main component and based on user selection I put the selected graph component in that container. Putting in the container should not disrupt binding.

Just to summarize, I want to find a way to dynamically put the component in a another component. Ideally in Composite Design Pattern it should be fairly easy to determine component in runtime. I am not able to figure that out in angular 2.

Comment: Check the dynamic component loader https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

Comment: Thanks, It might work for me, I will try to share a sample :)

Comment: `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` replaced `DynamicComponentLoader` a long time ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)
For an example of a dynamically loaded component, see this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uHr6zSEHjNlahGec6BP9?p=preview).
The key is `this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(Widget1, this.insertPoint);` and using `System.import` in the code to lazy load the component.  Although I'll point out that components aren't loaded into the shadow DOM until they are instantiated[*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html), so lazy loading may not be necessary.

`loadNextToLocation` is one of three methods in DynamicComponentLoader you can use, depending on how and where you want the component injected.  Note that `loadAsRoot` has an issue (current as of 2.0.0-beta.7) that prevents it loading properly in all cases.  See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7XnMoZFKF9TIO6evRpW8?p=preview) for details.